# Move files containing X but not containing Y

Tags: file, unix, find, move

To manage my backup sync folder, I am trying to come up with a command that would move files beginning with `string1*` but NOT ending with `*string2` from `/folder1` to `/folder2`

What would a command containing such two opposite conditions (HAS and HAS NOT) look like?

Comment: What sort of parameters do you have for `string1` and `string2`?  How big are the files?  Are they text, or binary? This sounds like something that could reasonably easily be done with some regex and unix tools, depending on your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `ls -d /folder1/string1* | grep -v 'string2$'`
do
   ls -ld $i | grep '^-' > /dev/null # Test that we have a regular file and not a directory etc.
   if [ $? == 0 ]; then
      mv $i /folder2
   fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
find /folder1 -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f \
-name 'string1*' \! -name '*string2' -exec cp -iv {} /folder2 +
```

*Note: If your have a older version of find you can replace `+` with `\;`*

Comment: BroSlow, do I get this right that I need to replace "-exec cp" with "-exec mv" to move the files, rather than copy them?

Also, if I run this command (cp or mv) I get
find: missing argument to `-exec'

Comment: @lockheed I would do `mv -iv`, to add some verbosity and in case you have any duplicate files already in `/folder2`. If your `find` doesn't take `+` use `\;`.

Answer (score 0):

To me this is another case for (what I shall denote) the `read while` pattern.

```
cd /folder1
ls string1* | grep -v 'string2$' | while read f; do mv $f /folder2; done
```

The other answers are good alternatives, and in particular, `find` can do a *lot*. But I always get a headache using `find`, and never quite use it enough to do so without the manpage open.

Also, starting with `ls` or a simple `find` to get a list of files, and then using any or all of `sed`, `awk`, `grep` or whatever you have to hand, to adjust/trim/extend this list, and then bunging it into a loop, is a crude(ish) but pretty powerful technique.

Comment: `find` does make it a lot easier to avoid errors cases though. e.g. This will fail to get dotfiles, files containing newlines, files starting with `-`, and files containing extraneous whitespace. Some of those can be fixed, but not all, which is why parsing `ls` is [generally viewed as bad](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: Sure, I agree – what you say is true in general, and if I were doing this somewhere deep in a script, then I'd use `find -print0` and a fancier `read`. But most of the time (in one-offs) I don't need to catch pathological filenames, but do want to do some simple transformation on the filenames without the punctuation explosion that non-trivial `find` invocations produce. It's unix: "crude but pretty powerful" is the key idea!